# How to change marshmallow notifications and viberation setting

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, settings

I gave samsung j7 prime with android marshmallow,  i turned off notifications in setting for perticular apps like messages, whatsapp. My phone is always in viberating mode. Whenever i recieves a messege my phone doesn't viberate. Is there any setting for that ? But i want notification to be turned off and whenever a new messege arrives it should viberate like my old samsung phone.

Answer (score 0):

The vibration is part of the notification, so if you turn the notification off, you don't get the vibration. You need to turn notifications back on. If your phone is in vibration mode then the notification will make your phone vibrate instead of making a noise, without you needing to change anything else. Even if your phone is in noisy mode, you can change the options in each app individually so its notification only vibrates without playing a sound.